# How to delete Cloudwatch alarms through AWS-CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have to delete almost 3K+ Cloudwatch alarms all in INSUFFICIENT_STATE.

So to deal with this I -
1. Took out the list of all the alarms in INSUFFICIENT state through terminal

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query 'MetricAlarms[*].AlarmName' --state-value INSUFFICIENT_DATA --output text > list.csv
```

2. Ran the file against a for loop through terminal only

```
for i in `cat list.csv` ;do aws cloudwatch delete-alarms --alarm-names $i ;done
```

3. After running this command the alerts are not removed  from AWS. I tested the script with 5 alarms in the list and the same worked. But this is not working for the file with more alarm names in it.

NOTE- I didn't get any error while running the command.

Comment: Do the file names have and special characters or spaces in them?

Comment: Can you check your CloudTrail logs and ensure the commands have been received?

Comment: delete-alarms has a fairly low tps limit, you could be getting throttled. Try adding a 0.5 second sleep in each iteration if the loop.

Comment: File names don't have special character, have verified them. @DavidWebster

Comment: CloudTrail logs do show the commands received @Maurice

Comment: I will try this and update, thanks @Tartaglia for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

As Dejan suggested, the [rate limit for deleteAlarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html) is 3 transactions per second.  This script deleted four thousand alarms in an hour:

```
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\t'
for alarm in $(aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query 'MetricAlarms[*].AlarmName' --state-value INSUFFICIENT_DATA --output text); do                         
  echo $alarm; 
  aws cloudwatch delete-alarms --alarm-names $alarm 1>/dev/null; 
  sleep 0.5;
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```